# Find the Data in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have model called report

```
create_table "ireports", force: true do |t|
 t.string   "reference"
 t.string   "name"
 t.integer  "weight"
 t.datetime "created_at"
 t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

When user came and type the **reference and weight**, display the particular report..

How can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in home controller

```
def index
end

def xyz
  @report = Ireport.where(reference: params[:report][:reference], weight: params[:report][:weight]).first
end
```

and for form field on index page.

```
<%= form_for :report, :url => xyz_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :reference %>
  <%= f.text_field :reference %>
  <%= f.label :weight %>
  <%= f.text_field :weight %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

and in your routes file add.

```
get '/xyz', to: 'homes#xyz', as: 'xyz'
```

Comment: error undefined local variable or method `xyz_path'

Comment: you have to add route in your routes file. I am updating answer.

Comment: can update without user, i not use user model

Comment: yes have updated answer.

Comment: got error undefined method `label_for' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x0000010132d7a8>

Comment: try f.label or remove that and create label with pure html.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59585/discussion-between-faiq-adam-and-nitin-verma).

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably be best using the [`find_by`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-by) method:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
Class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def lookup
      @user = Ireport.find_by reference: params[:reference], weight: [:weight]
   end
end
```

Comment: how display home#index, form field to find report

Comment: i upload image http://imgur.com/R2AZQEa

Comment: It show in home#index, i don't want user controller

Comment: can you come chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror